# Parse docx from HTML form input

Tags: javascript, html, forms, base64

I have an HTML form with various types of input. One of these inputs is a file input. I allow all types of files at the moment. From the form POST I get a base64 encoded body.

How can I extract just the file details (still base64 encoded) using JavaScript?

Comment: Do yo want display content of base64?

Comment: I need the file to be base64 encoded for the next step of the process

Answer (score 0):

What you need is called the Window btoa() Method:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_btoa.asp
The preceding is a tutorial on how to use it.

I created a calculator a while ago, here's the link:
http://s94441163.onlinehome.us/RAMON/CONTENT/Atch/Atch/Base64.htm

I hope that helps,
Ramon